# Why do we search for RidgeCV alphas on a logarithmic scale?

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn, data-science

Everybody says you should provide a logarithmically scaled range of values for RidgeCV to search over in estimating the optimal alpha value. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

Because you want to try a larger range of alpha values. Bear in mind that taking a large set of alphas to perform CV will be costly (regarding computational resources), thus, with a `np.logspace(-3, 5, 10)` you will try 10 alphas with really different magnitudes, from `10**-3` up to `10**5`.